# Nuget Pack Tfs - wrong path to dll

Tags: tfs, nuget

My Nuget-Pack-Step in the TFS isn't working, because it is searching my DLL-File at the wrong path.

My Actual path to the dll is:

```
D:\Agent1\_work\21\s\src\MyProjectName\bin\Any CPU\Release\netstandard2.0\MyProjectName.dll
```

But the Nuget-Pack step path is missing my `Any CPU`. But I don't see an option to set it.

```
'D:\Agent1\_work\21\s\src\MyProjectName\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\MyProjectName.dll'.
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NuGet Pack task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget#pack-nuget-packages) takes the following arguments:

- Path to csproj or nuspec file(s) to pack
- Configuration to package

I suspect that you haven't set the configuration property to Any CPU resulting in the task not being able to find your DLL.

Comment: But it is missing the $(BuildPlattform) not the $(BuildConfiguration) ?

Comment: I fixed it by copying the files to the desired path - which leaded me tot the conclusion that Nuget-Pack isn't supporting the .netcore v2 dlls.